# Visual Studio 2022 C++ Modules compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules, visual-c++-2022

I am trying to learn how modules work in C++20 and created a simple hello world example in Visual Studio 2022 Community (Version 17.5.3)

hello1.ixx:

```
export module hello1;

import <iostream>;

export void hello() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world from hello1\n";
}
```

hello2.ixx:

```
export module hello2;

import <iostream>;

export void hello() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world from hello2\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
import hello1;
import hello2;

int main() {
  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

This program compiles just fine and when run I get this output:

> Hello, world from hello1

And if I change the order of the imports:

```
import hello2;
import hello1;
```

I get output:

> Hello, world from hello2

Afaik the order of imports should not matter, and this program should fail compilation since there are two definitions of the hello() function and the call to it is ambiguous.

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **ODR Violation**.

Comment: I believe that's the intended behavior - the first import of an export is taken and those afterwards don't count

Comment: Its the way the linker works, first definition it encounters makes it happy.  Pretty crucial to use namespaces to avoid such accidents.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, but is it valid C++? Or is this undefined behavior or implementation dependent?

Comment: @MBobrik On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules under Module Ownership this passage I don't understand:

If two matching declarations are attached to different modules, and they both declare names with external linkage, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required if neither is reachable from the other. In practice, there are two models:


- In the weak module ownership model, such declarations are considered to declare the same entity.

 - In the strong module ownership model, they are considered to declare different entities.

Comment: I tried it with g++ and then get this error:
main.cpp:5:8: error: call of overloaded ‘hello()’ is ambiguous

Comment: I believe it is the compiler settings - g++ got the 'strong' by default and therefore it screams 'error' (as it in my opinion should). With VC compiler is most probably 'weak' the default and therefore no error. In my opinion, it should be at least a warning - otherwise you are in for a surprise and a long search for the cause.

Comment: Thank you all for comments and clarifications. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Per [[basic.link]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.link#9.sentence-2):

> If multiple declarations of the same name with external linkage would declare the same entity except that they are attached to different modules, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

Having no diagnostic be required means that compilers don't *have* to detect this circumstance. Your code is still broken, but compilers are not required to do what would be necessary to detect this breakage.

Exported names have external linkage. Therefore, this passage applies. You should do what you reasonably can to avoid this by using proper namespace scoping for code exported by a module.

Comment: Thank you Nicol for a clear explanation.

Comment: Can we make a linter for that, throw an error and not compile? This is a disaster that it's allowed. MSVC allows this but from what I saw, Clang throws an error.

Comment: @KulaGGin: "*Can we make a linter for that, throw an error and not compile?*" Does cpplint operate on multiple translation units? I thought it only checked things that were relevant to the compilation of a single TU and not the linker. What we're talking about would be essentially a linker error, not a compiler error.